# ¿Cómo puedo enviar por parámetro en un procedimiento almacenado una variable?

Tags: php, laravel

Las fechas son las que quiero pasar, pero me genera un error al colocarlas.

Necesito ayuda para poder enviarlas dentro de este procedimiento para poder realizarlo correctamente:

```
$fInicio = $datos->fecha_inicio;
$fFinal = $datos->fecha_fin;
$consulta = TblMetas::where('tbl_meta.ind_activo',1) 
      ->JOIN('tbl_cat_delegaciones   AS b', 'tbl_meta.id_delegacion',   '=', 'b.id')
      ->JOIN('tbl_cat_ups            AS c', 'tbl_meta.id_ups',          '=', 'c.id')
      ->JOIN('cat_master             AS d', 'tbl_meta.id_servicio',     '=', 'd.id')
      ->JOIN('cat_master             AS z', 'tbl_meta.id_estatus_meta', '=', 'z.id')
      ->JOIN('tbl_encuesta           AS e', 'tbl_meta.id_encuesta',     '=', 'e.id')
      ->JOIN('tbl_configuracion_meta AS f', 'tbl_meta.id',              '=', 'f.id_meta')
  
      ->orderBy('tbl_meta.id_delegacion', 'ASC', 'tbl_meta.ind_activo', 'DESC', 'tbl_meta.dtm_fecha_inicio', 'ASC')
      ->select(DB::raw('"" ln_usuario, "" ln_apaterno, "" ln_amaterno, tbl_meta.id,
                         b.ln_descripcion AS delegacion,
                       c.ln_descripcion AS ups,
                         d.descripcion    AS servicio,
                         e.ln_titulo      AS encuesta,
                         tbl_meta.id_estatus_meta,
                         z.descripcion    AS estatus_m,
           calcProgresoEnc(c.id, e.id,"2022/01/01", "2022/01/20") AS num_asignados,
                         DATE_FORMAT(tbl_meta.dtm_fecha_inicio, "%d-%m-%Y") AS dtm_fecha_inicio, 
                       DATE_FORMAT(tbl_meta.dtm_fecha_fin, "%d-%m-%Y") AS dtm_fecha_fin'
                         )
         

         )
```

Comment: Hola tal vez te sirva este ejemplo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vs7fo9sGS04&t=607s

Comment: no me sirve ya que las variables ya las tengo, solo necesito enviarlas como parametro dentro del procedimiento almacenado